# SQL Insert New Record if not exists else update the existing one

Tags: mysql, sql-update, query-performance, mysql-slow-query-log

I have 2 tables Staging & Main Table both has the columns SKU and Price. Records are inserted into staging table from there depending on the record its decided whether new record is to be inserted or update an existing. I have written multiple queries which are working fine but its taking longer than normal. What I am doing is:

```html
Staging Table where data initially inserted into 

+----------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| indexid  |  Persisted   |    sku    | price |                                                           Logic                                                           |
+----------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | No           |   4567456 | 10.99 | This row doesn't exists in main table so need to be inserted and update the persisted to NewProduct                       |
|        2 | No           |   5463454 |  5.99 | This row exists and price matching then this simply need to be updated the persisted to PriceMatched                      |
|        3 | No           |   5645654 |  4.75 | This row exists but price not matching, so new row to be inserted, updated existing record in both tables to PriceUpdated |
|        4 | PriceUpdated |   2222222 |  3.00 |                                                                                                                           |
|        5 | NewProduct   |   5555555 |  4.00 |                                                                                                                           |
|        6 | PriceMatched |   7685765 |  5.00 |                                                                                                                           |
|        7 | PriceUpdated |   6574567 |  3.99 |                                                                                                                           |
+----------+--------------+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```html
+---------+--------------+---------+-------+
| indexid |    status    |   sku   | price |
+---------+--------------+---------+-------+
|       1 | Active       | 5635674 | 10.99 |
|       2 | Active       | 5463454 |  5.99 |
|       3 | Active       | 5645654 |  2.75 |
|       4 | PriceUpdated | 2222222 |  3.00 |
|       5 | PriceUpdated | 5555555 |  4.00 |
|       6 | PriceMatched | 7685765 |  5.00 |
|       7 | PriceUpdated | 6574567 |  3.99 |
+---------+--------------+---------+-------+
```

If Product not exist in main table then insert new record and update the staging table with persisted = 'NewProduct'

I am selecting all the records from staging table where persisted = 'No'
Then Insert new record

```html
UPDATE stagingTable SET persisted = 'NewProduct' WHERE indexid = '${indexID}';
```

Else Check if existing product price matching then update persisted = 'PriceMatched'

```html
UPDATE stagingTable SET persisted = 'PriceMatched' WHERE indexid = '${indexID}' ;
```

If price not matched then insert new record into Main Table and update existing record status = 'PriceUpdated' And staging table persisted = 'PriceUpdated'

```html
UPDATE mainTable SET productstatus = 'PriceUpdated' WHERE indexid = '${indexID}';
UPDATE stagingTable SET persisted = 'PriceUpdated' WHERE indexid = '${indexID}';
```

Insertions are working fine but updates are taking quite long 10000 records taking around 15-20 Minutes I am inserting and updating by batch insert and update.

This is the logic I have

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have updated my question and added more details with the sample tables

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment

Comment: You say "batch", but I don't see any batching.  I would expect a total of only 3 queries (IODKUs and/or UPDATEs) for the 7 rows.  Or even for a million rows.  Probably there is no need for hauling ids around.

Comment: Some db versions actually support EXPLAIN on update queries. But if yours does not, refactor your update as a SELECT, EXPLAIN your select and see what sort of indexes will help your performance. Benchmark if INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE provides improvement. Also does your staging table need to contain all records or can you delete as you resolve and buy yourself a few cycles? Sometimes dropping constraints, making updates, and then reapplying constraints can help performance but there's tradeoffs.